# Does Zookeeper require SSD disks for Apache Kafka Clusters?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, disk, solid-state-drive

we want to install kafka cluster and 3 zookeeper servers

kafka should use the zookeeper servers in order to save the metadata on the zookeeper servers

ZK Data and Log files should be on disks, which have least contention from other I/O activities. Ideally the ZK data and ZK transaction log files should be on different disks, so that they don't contend for the IO resource.

Note that, it isn't enough to just have partitions but they have to be different disks to ensure performance.

So dose zookeeper server must use SSD disks ?

if yes what are the minimum requirements for zoo disks as IO ,etc.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/current/zookeeper/deployment.html#disks) recommends the following configuration when running Zookeeper in Production environments:

> **Disks**
>   Disk performance is vital to maintaining a healthy ZooKeeper cluster.
>   Solid state drives (SSD) are highly recommended as ZooKeeper must have
>   low latency disk writes in order to perform optimally. Each request to
>   ZooKeeper must be committed to to disk on each server in the quorum
>   before the result is available for read. A dedicated SSD of at least
>   64 GB in size on each ZooKeeper server is recommended for a production
>   deployment. You can use autopurge.purgeInterval and
>   autopurge.snapRetainCount to automatically cleanup ZooKeeper data and
>   lower maintenance overhead.

Comment: I see from your answer that SSD are recommended , but what are the minimum requirements for zoo disks as IO ,etc. , can you give details about the minimum read / write speed , etc

Comment: @Judy It depends. SSDs reduce the ZooKeeper write latency. You can use SATA but you should expect higher latency.

Comment: yes but what I am asking about details of numbers , for example lets say that SATA disk are meet the requirements but how to know the requirements in number as IO ?

Comment: beside confluent do you see any other documentation ?

Comment: But there is no clear answer to this question. It depends on your application and the requirements. The best way to go is to test multiple configurations and pick the one that meets your requirements.

Comment: You can check [Apache Kafka docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) as well.